# $(N^2 - 1)/(N - 1) = N+1$ and its relation to sorting square matrices.

Tags: algorithms, square-numbers, sorting

I'm working on a problem that involves sorting the members of square matrices into groups. Here are the sorting rules:

1. Group size equals the square root of the number of members in the matrix
2. Every member has to end up in a group
3. Every group must be composed of members who have not been together in a prior group, **aka** no overlap
4. The matrix must be broken into sets of groups until every member has been grouped with every other member exactly once

Take a 3x3 matrix for example:

\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{matrix}

Following the sorting rules, all necessary sets of groups are:

\begin{matrix}
1: & [1,2,3] & [4,5,6] & [7,8,9]\\
2: & [1,4,7] & [2,5,8] & [3,6,9]\\
3: & [1,5,9] & [2,6,7] & [3,4,8]\\
4: & [1,6,8] & [2,4,9] & [3,5,7]
\end{matrix}

Notice that there are 4 sets of groups. For a 4x4, there are 5 sets of groups. I expect this behavior continues indefinitely which is why I brought up $(N^2-1)/(N-1) = N+1$ in the title.

I wrote a python program to compute these sets of groups for an arbitrarily sized square matrix: https://github.com/hayden-blair/squares/

**PROBLEM**

My member selection algorithm is greedy... For 5x5's and higher, The algorithm is selecting groups that force incomplete sets. Some members are unable to be sorted because the previously selected groups limit the choices available for future selections in such a way that the sorting criteria cannot be satisfied. I can find the solutions on paper, but I can't find a pattern that lets me do the math correctly through my algorithm.

Does anyone have any resources they could point me to on this topic? I'm sure something like this has been done before...

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: Consider only the groups which contain the element $1$. From your example you should see that every set of groups matches exactly $N-1$ elements that have not previously been with $1$ in a group. This means that you need exactly $(N^2-1)/(N-1)=N+1$ groups in order to match $1$ with every element exactly once.

Comment: Awesome! I could do the proof on paper, but I couldn't find the proof within the context of grouping. Thank you much for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this has been done before! In the language of [experimental design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments) your task is to create a [balanced incomplete block design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design) and to [resolve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Resolvable_2-designs) the design into "parallel" classes.

There is a standard notation to characterize BIBDs:

1. $v$, the number of points (or "treatments", in experimental design)
2. $b$, the number of blocks
3. $r$, the number of blocks containing a given point
4. $k$, the number of points in a block
5. $\lambda$, the number of blocks containing any two distinct points

These parameters are not all independent, since $bk=vr$ and $\lambda(v-1)=r(k-1)$. Many authors will use just the three parameters $(v,k,\lambda)$ to characterize a BIBD.

In your problem, you have $(v,k,\lambda)=(N^2, N, 1)$ which corresponds to the well-known [affine plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane_(incidence_geometry)). Every affine plane is [resolvable](http://math.ucdenver.edu/%7Ewcherowi/courses/m6406/resolvable.pdf), i.e., it is possible to partition the $b:=N(N+1)$ blocks in the affine plane into $r:=N+1$ parallel classes (what you're calling "groups"), each class being a partition of the set of points. (In fact the affine plane is considered the [classical example of a resolvable BIBD](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01835977.pdf).)

Since every affine plane is resolvable, it's enough for you to generate any old affine plane, and then deduce the resolution by inspection. This may be cheating, but you can find BIBD generators online, for example [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/ibd/man/bibd.html).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed feedback and for all of the incredible resources you pointed out! I am going to need to spend some time digging into these resources you mentioned, but it sounds like these BIBD's are exactly what I needed for my project.